# Extending the "trigger area" that activates the dropdown menu.

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

[image: Dropdown Menu]

Currently, only when the mouseover occurs near the phone icon or the little arrow-up area, will the dropdown menu not disappear when you move your cursor down to click on the links in the dropdownmenu.

When someone mouses over from the word 'Contact', the dropdown menu disappears as soon as he moves the cursor. I want the dropdown menu to remain as user moves the cursor down from the word 'Contact' .

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="Navigation">

        <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="OP" id="OPM1"><img src="images/order.png"   /><a  href="Orders.html">Orders</a></li>

                    <li class="OP"><img src="images/contact.png" /><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact</a>
                            <div class="extended">
                                <div class="arrow-up"></div>

                                <ul class="smallNav">
                                    <li><a href="#">+65-65553333</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/yourfanpage/12345678" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/yourtwitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="www.gmail.com" target="_blank">enquiry [at] foodstant [dot] com</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        </ul>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.Navigation { background:background: rgb(246,248,249); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%, rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%, rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%, rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,248,249,1)), color-stop(46%,rgba(229,235,238,1)), color-stop(65%,rgba(215,222,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,247,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f8f9', endColorstr='#f5f7f9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */ 
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;

    box-shadow: -3px -5px 10px  #888888;
    font-size: 26px;

    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
}

.Navigation ul li {  position: relative; list-style: none; padding: 17px 10px; }

.Navigation ul li a { font-size: 26px; font-weight: bold; color: white; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 2px black; }

.Navigation ul li:hover { background: url(images/hover.png) repeat-x; height: 43px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px black inset; padding: 20px 9px; border-left: 1px solid #a4a4a4; border-right: 1px solid #a4a4a4;} 

.Navigation ul li:hover { background: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; height: auto; border: none; }


.arrow-up { width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-bottom: 15px solid #6a6a63; position: absolute; left: 20px; top: -15px; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended { position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 0; width: 220px; background: url(images/dropdownback.png); z-index: 1000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); box-shadow: 0 0 8px black; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid white; display: none; color: white; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended img { display: block; margin: 5px auto 15px auto; -webkit-box-reflect:below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.8, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.5))); }

.Navigation  ul li .extended a { font-size:14px;}

.Navigation  ul li .extended h2, .Navigation ul li .ultraNav h2 { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 16px; text-shadow: 0 1px 2px black; color: white; background: url(images/headerback.png) repeat-x; height: 20px; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px;  }

.Navigation ul li .extended span { padding-left: 10px; font-size: 11px; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav { border-top: 1px solid rgba(141,141,141,0.50);  padding: 10px; height: 100px;  }

.Navigation ul li .extended ul.smallNav li { width: 200px; padding: 0; line-height: 22px; font-weight: bold; background: url(images/linkback.png) no-repeat; }

.extended ul li {float:left;}

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav li:first-child { margin: 0; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav li:last-child { margin-bottom: 10px; }

.Navigation ul li:hover .extended { display: block; }

.Navigation ul li ul li:hover a { color: white; } 

#navbar {

}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-position:inside;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


#navbar ul li {     
        display: inline;
        padding:0 20px 0px 0px; 
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        list-style-type:disc;
    }

#navbar ul li.OP {
        padding-left: 15px;

}   

#navbar ul li.OP img {
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

#navbar li a:link {
  color: #EF174A;
  }

#navbar li a:visited {
  color: #BF4100;
  }

 #navbar li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color:#D2D2D2;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  }

 #navbar li a:active {
  color: #918FBC;
  } 

li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}  

#navbar ul li.OP a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav li a { color: #c7c7c7 !important; text-shadow: none !important;  } 

.Navigation ul li .extended ul.smallNav li a:hover { color: white !important;}
```

Comment: This code seems to be working. I pasted it directly into this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mBBb6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `arrow-up` DIV with another DIV like this:

```
<div class="arrow-container"><div class="arrow-up"></div></div>
```

Then add the `arrow-container` style as:

```
.arrow-container { margin-top:-16px; height:16px; }
```

Comment: Thanks a great deal =) . Your solution worked. How did you figure out the values for `margin-top` and `height` ?

Comment: Both height are based on `arrow-up` reposition, which came from `top:-15px`. But since there's still 1 pixel gap between it and the "Contact" text, it's moved further more by 1 pixel and increased the height to 16px so it fills both upper and lower gap.

Comment: Oh, so you actually created a small area which mimic-ed the `arrow-up` area right ? Very interesting idea .

Comment: Yes, the space was necessary since the menu's margin created a gap between itself and the handset image & "Contact" text area. The gap doesn't belong to all of them.